# Why is the following set neither open nor closed?

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, problem-solving

I would have said answer $(ii)$, because I though it was between 0 and infinity but the correct answer is $(iv)$ which I don't get why.

I have really trouble with these types of exercises. 
**Why is it countable here?
Why is a countable set necessarily not open?**

thanks

[image]

Comment: Guess you need to recall the definition of an [open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set#Euclidean_space).

Comment: It's countable since it's enumerated by $n \in \mathbb N^*$ which is countable. The set is a sequence of points with an accumulation point in $(0, 0)$.

Answer (score 3):

You are right, it is not closed because you can find a sequence of points of $E$ that converges to a point outside of $E$.

It is also not open, since $E$ has at most a countable number of points. Since it is a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, it can not be open (take a point of $E$, if there is a ball that is contained in $E$, it would have an uncountable number of points).

Comment: Could you please clarify why if a set is countable that implies that it can not be open please? I have trouble grasping that fully.

Comment: More directly, $E$ is not open because for example $(1, 1) \in E$ but $E$ does not contain any open ball $B_\epsilon(1, 1)$ with $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: If a set is open, it contains a non-empty ball, which has the same cardinality as $\mathbb R$, therefore this set has at least the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Why does it not contain an open Ball in (1,1)?

Answer (score 0):

While cardinality provides one way of seeing that $E$ isn't open, it isn't the only way. Another fairly easy way is to note that $A = \{(x,y)| x \not \in \mathbb Q \}$ is dense in $\mathbb  R ^ 2$ but is disjoint from $E$. That would be impossible if $E$ were open.

Answer (score 0):

$E$ is not closed since it does not contain $(0,0)$ which is a limit point of $E$.

$E$ is not open, since it contains $(1,1)\in E$, but $E$ does not contain any disk (or ball) centred at $(1,1)$. In particular, for every $(x,y)\in E$, we have that $x\le 1$. If $E$ was open, then there would be points $(x,y)\in E$, with $x>1$.

Comment: why does it not contain a ball(1,1)?

Comment: @SoHCahToha If it did, it would also contain elements of the form $(x,1)$, where $x>1$.

Comment: I'm really confused